# How to distinguish between user types when authenticating with JWT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt

In my app (Mongo,Express,Node,React), I'm currently authenticating users from the client to the server using JSON Web tokens. However, I want to be able to have two different types of users access different halves of the app. What is the best way to go about this? I currently have both types of users saved in the same model with a boolean that differentiates them. To clarify, different types of users would be able to access different API's as well as different portions of the client side app.

Is there a package that handles this? JWT feature?

Comment: good question. was wondering the same thing just to differnciate mobile and web users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wanted to add a little to the suggested answer. A lot I am taking from how Auth0 uses jwt. You might want to play with it so see how they handle authentication and protecting their routes. Another thing that really helped me understand ways to use jwt was playing with the debugger on the [jwt website](https://jwt.io/).

### Allowing users to access different API endpoints

A jwt token can be [decoded](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode) by anyone. Anyone can see what is on the token. The important part of a jwt is that it has a signature. If someone wanted to take a token, change the information and then access your api, then the **signature** would be messed up and that token should be rejected.

All you need to do is create a route middleware. If a route is protected the user sends the jwt in the header. The middleware will do 2 things:

1. Check the signature of the token to ensure the token is valid and has not been tampered with.
2. Decode the token to see what is on the JSON. Since a jwt is just a JSON you can add any property to it you want. Add a property permissions and set what level that users permissions are. Here is a tutorial from auth0 about how real life companies like slack could use jwt tokens to define what a user can and can't do. A lot of the same principles apply to exactly what you want to do. [Auth0 with multi tenant apps](https://auth0.com/docs/tutorials/using-auth0-with-multi-tenant-apps)

### How can I restrict users client-side using React?

I saw this question in the comments and will throw the answer here in case anyone was interested. If someone really wanted to, they can take their token, change it, and get to any visual component (in react). The reason that is the case is you don't want to keep any token signature secrets on your client. But even if someone did change their token, they wouldn't be able to do any damage. If they tried to send a request to the server, their token would be rejected and your api would be protected.

### React Router and Dynamic Routing

For the 99.9% of your users that don't mess with their token, the best way to decide what parts of the site they are allowed to use is by using [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router). Since React is a single page application there is only one static html file that will send your build to the client. With other frameworks different routes on your server will send a different page at different static endpoints. To mimic this page behavior with react, it is very common that people use React Router. React Router creates dynamic routes so when users insert endpoints into the browser it can mimic how typical static sites work.

It can also be used to restrict users from accessing certain components. Once a user logs in, you can send the decoded token information and save it to your react state. One of those would be your permissions parameter. With react router, when a user attempts to navigate to a location that requires permissions you can reference their state and redirect them either to the protected component or back to an authorized catch, back to where they came from, the login page, etc. Basically wherever you want.

[Here is a, slightly confusing implementation on the react router documentation site about implementing restricted endpoints.](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)

[Another tutorial from auth0 using react router to restrict users](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login). Scroll to the header **Process the Authentication Result**

Comment: :D no problem! It took me a little while to wrap my head around jwt's. Auth0 has a lot of stuff on github that can be helpful when decoding or checking signatures. https://github.com/auth0

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 ways that you may do this:

1. When you are encoding the JWT token, encode the user role also.
2. When you decode the JWT token and get the user's ID, for example, query your data store to get that user's role.

Most of the packages will allow you to define what you want to encode.

Tips:

1. Always set an expiry on your tokens. It's simply a date stored on
   the JWT. When you decode the token just make sure that the date is
   in future, if not deny access.
2. Create a middleware that checks the user's role. For example:

```
router.get('/restricted-area', requiresAdmin, (req, res, next) => {
  // only admin can access this
});

function requiresAdmin(req, res, next) {
  if(req.user.admin !== true) {
     res.status(401).end();
  } else {
     next();
  }
}
```

Comment: good call - that should be pretty easily workable on the server side. Any tips on processing the token in React?

Comment: There is no processing required on the React side. Just store the token in localstorage or anywhere you prefer. And maybe define a request interceptor that will add the token to the request headers each time you make one. When the user logs out, simply clear the token.

Comment: how then will I determine which pages in the react app a user is allowed to access? Ideally I'd be able to distinguish this based on user type. If that's not possible, is there a conventional way to do what I'm talking about?

Comment: I am not a react user but there should be a `hook` where you can make a check. For example `beforeCreated` hook in VueJs allows you to perform a task before a module is created.